# $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\alpha\beta}$=?

Tags: metric-tensor, relativity

Good day. I am self-studying general relativity, and I have a quick question on the inverse metric tensor:
I am aware that $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\nu\alpha}=\delta^{\mu}_{\alpha}$. I do not know, however, what $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\alpha\beta}$ is. I thought I could perhaps manipulate the expression as follows:
\begin{align}
g^{\mu\nu}g_{\alpha\beta} & = g_{\alpha\mu}g_{\beta\nu}g^{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu} \\
& = \delta^{\nu}_{\alpha}\delta^{\mu}_{\beta} \\
\end{align}
However, a similar procedure generates $\delta^{\mu}_{\alpha}\delta^{\nu}_{\beta}$
So perhaps I am completely off-base. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can’t have three or more of the same index in a tensor, so your manipulation is invalid.

Comment: Here is something that always helps me check. The rule of thumb is: what ever indices appear on the LHS of the equation have to appear on the RHS. Any additional indices must be repeated otherwise there is a typo. You can’t have more than two of the same index in a tensor as pointed out by @G.Smith. If you follow these rules, it is quite hard to make a mistake with indices at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's nothing in particular — or, in other words, it doesn't simplify like the contraction $g^{\mu\nu}g_{\nu\alpha}=\delta^{\mu}_{\alpha}$ does.  It's simply a tensor of type ${2 \choose 2}$.